# IOS App ATS HTTPS Request Configuration

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, mobile-application

We have an **IOS App**. It's login based on Server URL. We have to submit a username, password, and Server URL. But Our Sever Web URL is running in HTTPS. But app only supporting HTTP URL. Can we enable https server request through **info.plist** file.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to all few thing in your plist Check this [Blog](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)
You can add exceptions for specific domains in your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

You can also ignore all app transport security restrictions with a single key, if your app has a good reason to do so:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```